# What does this sentence say?

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question:
早速園内をのぞいてみました。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0521.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

My attempt at translation:
"At once they cleared inside the garden."

I dont really know how else to translate this sentence, however, I also have difficulties connecting with the context from before. I could see the aforementioned nursery school having "cleared" their garden of children. Basically calling them in after letting them play for some time in the garden.
However, this comes pretty much out of the blue and therefore I find it rather improbable.

So maybe I just misunderstood the whole thing and someone can tell me what they actually tell us there ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「覗{のぞ}く」 means "***to take a look into***"

> 「早速園内{さっそくえんない}をのぞいてみました。」

simply means:

> "I took a look into the kindergarten right away."

You probably had in mind another verb 「除{のぞ}く」("***to remove***") to come up with "to clear", but 「園内を除く」 does not make much sense in the first place.